# variable set to function call returns None

Tags: python

I am making a simple ceaser cipher program in python, and this concept has confused me for quite some time.

What I do is ask for raw_input from users to determine the message and key for the cipher like so:

```
def user_input():
    ask_user = raw_input("Do you want to encrypt or decrypt a     message?")
    if ask_user in "encrypt e".split():
        message = get_message()
        key = get_key()
        translate_message(message, key)
    else:
        print 'Type encrypt or e for encryption, or decrypt or d doe decryption'
        user_input()
```

This collects the message and key, and passes into translate_message for the actual encryption.

Here is my get_message function:

```
def get_message():
    get_user_message = raw_input('enter in your message\n')
    vm = validate_message(get_user_message)
    if not vm:
        print 'Please enter a valid message'
        get_message()
    else:
        print get_user_message
        return get_user_message
```

I want to validate the input to make sure the user enters the correct values. If the value is incorrect according to validate_message,it calls get_message again, else get_message returns the original value.

Here's validate_message:

```
def validate_message(message):
    if not re.match(r'^[A-Za-z]+$', message):
        return False
    return True
```

Just a simple check (I like my functions to do one thing)

Normally, this runs fine and the key & message values are returned like normal. The problem comes when I intentionally input incorrect values to test my validation.

Here's what translate_message returns without incorrect values(it just returns the two values):

```
'test_message', 22
```

The confusion comes when I input incorrect values. Say I enter 3333 (will recall get_message() because of incorrect value), until the user enters correct input. translate_message returns None if the user enters any kind of incorrect value before successfully entering a value

```
None, 22
```

In the get_message() function I add a print statement right before the return value, which prints out the correct value as expected. So why is

key = get_key()

equaling to None? I went through the logic in get_message() and I can't see where the return value is equal to None when it should return the users correct guess.

Any help is appreciated, and if there is a better way to implement this type of logic, I'd like to know! I'm fairly new to python programming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `return` was buried in the `else` clause of the `if` statement, execution fell off the bottom of the function, and Python returns `None` by default when that happens.

Your recursive call to `get_message()` will not return to the original caller (the `user_input` function in this case) unless you actually return the value from the recursive call with the statement `return get_message()`.

However, you may want to consider a loop instead of recursion for this; a monkey banging at the keyboard could eventually cause a stack overflow when using recursion for input validation.  Here is an example of an iterative version of this:

```
def get_message():
    while 1:
        get_user_message = raw_input('enter in your message\n')
        vm = validate_message(get_user_message)
        if not vm:
            print 'Please enter a valid message'
        else:
            print get_user_message
            return get_user_message
```

The `return` will break out of the `while` loop whenever you have valid data, and return it to the caller.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with the recursive call. My program works like it should, thanks!